# What would be the correct usage to refer of a timesheet that was due on a previous pay period?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

What would be the correct usage to refer of a timesheet that was due on a previous pay period?

'...pay period ending on 5/01/2016'

or

'...pay period ending in 5/01/2016'.

I struggle a lot with *in/on* usage. I would appreciate some didactic knowledge in the correct usage for 'on/in' in your answer.

Comment: See the dictionary entry for "on". Compare with the dictionary entry for "end in".

Comment: You know how to use a dictionary.

Comment: Also it's usually "refer to," not "refer on."

Comment: A pay period would end **on** a specific date or it might fall on a day **in** a period of time (month, quarter, week, etc.).  e.g., _I get paid **on** the first Friday **in** June and it usually posts to my account **in** the afternoon._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time periods generally begin and end *on* a day, or *in* a month or a year. 
So "ending on 5/01/2016" is correct.

In some contexts, particularly US and Business English, the more succinct "ending 5/01/2016" is also quite common. In British English, it's less common to omit the "on".